# How can I use Keyboard Maestro to select all content in an Excel cell?

Tags: keyboard, mac, ms-office

How to enable select all contents in KeyboardMaestro? I don't see any option but I saw a guide here. It wasn't clear though.

[Keyboard shortcut to select all text in a cell in Excel](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31306/keyboard-shortcut-to-select-all-text-in-a-cell-in-excel/112848#112848?newreg=953573d71b454bf286082057872e0f8a)

Comment: Well I got the work around. it's actually self-explanatory. search "Type a Keystroke" action and add it as your action!

Comment: Could you please shift your comment to an answer so that it is easier for others to find.

Answer (score 2):

Well I got the work around. it's actually self-explanatory. search "Type a Keystroke" action and add it as your action!